# How to setup development environment with AngularJS? I'm having trouble getting basic AngularJS app up and running

Tags: angularjs, npm, localhost, httpserver

I'm still new to AngularJS and am trying to figure out how I should start/begin my app making. I first made two files index.html and app.js, then proceeded to use the `npm init` command to make my package.json file, inside of which looks like (I added the start property in scripts) :

```
{
      "name": "app",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "idk",
      "main": "app.js",
      "scripts": {
            "start": "npm run start",
            "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "author": "Me",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "http-server": "^0.11.1"
      }
    }
```

And my file directory looks something like this:

```
testProgram -> app.js
testProgram -> index.html
testProgram -> package.json
testProgram -> package-lock.json
testProgram -> node_modules -> angular
```

I've done a bunch of random commands on this, and am not sure how exactly I got the node_modules package, so if someone knows the purpose of this and or how I got it that would be great.

When I run `npm start` from the testProgram directory, the terminal goes on a somewhat infinite loop and displays this nonstop:

```
> app@1.0.0 start /Users/Me/AngularJS/testProgram
> npm run start


> app@1.0.0 start /Users/Me/AngularJS/testProgram
> npm run start


> app@1.0.0 start /Users/Me/AngularJS/testProgram
> npm run start


> app@1.0.0 start /Users/Me/AngularJS/testProgram
> npm run start
```

And so I was wondering how I could get a proper developing environment up so that I could see my edits/changes. I want to be able to run my app on any localhost or http-server. How should I go about doing this? Also, any tips (preferably a general step by step explanation) regarding setting up angularJS apps would be extremely appreciated as I'm uncertain of the way I'm doing it. (I've looked at many tutorials and there are many ways to approach this, but this way seems most common and straightforward.)

Here's my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Angular Test</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
        {{7 + 17}}
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my app.js:

```
var modone = angular.module("App",['main']);
var modtwo =  angular.module("main", []);
modtwo.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope) {
        // no code yet
});
```

Comment: The reason you're getting the loop is because scripts/start command is what runs when you type npm start and in scripts/start you've got 'npm run start' hence the infinite loop.

Comment: Not entirely sure if I understand this, how would I go about fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of impossible to comment much more without seeing your app.js or index.html but this might get you started...

I think your main problem is you scripts section in your package.json file should be:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "http-server"
  }
```

This should start your http-server as opposed to getting stuck in a loop.

Also looking at your package file you need to install (and save in the file) a lot more files first. Mine looks a bit like this for AngularJS (I've cut out a lot of specific stuff I use):

```
{
  "name": "AngularJS App",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "lite-server",
    "gulp": "gulp"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.7.8",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.7.8",
    "del": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "jasmine": "^3.3.1",
    "karma": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
  }
}
```

You'll notice my scripts/start launches 'lite-server' which is the local http-server I have installed globally. Details are [enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server).

You'll need to include of the dependencies in your index.html file and obviously have a proper working app.js file (which is referenced last in your script tags).

There could be a million other things your missing but I hope this helps!

Comment: Is it required that I add more dependencies to my package.json before it works? Also, I've updated my post with code from my other 2 files.

Comment: All the dependencies that your app needs should be in the package.json file becuase if you were to download it from source control you would want to be able to type npm install and it install all the dependencies you need for your app. You can make it work without them being in there but it's bad practice.

Comment: You biggest problem is your npm start script is wrong and is not starting your http server.

Comment: I've updated my answer a bit to hopefully show where I think your main problem is.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! Also, I'm using lite-server and it works well!

Comment: Glad it's all working. Please accept the answer if it all worked.